# About Averages of Incomplete Additive Character Sums

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, character-sums

Let $p$ be a prime. Let $\omega$ be a $ p $-th root of unity. We know that $ \chi_\alpha (x) = \omega^{\alpha\cdot x} $ are the additive characters of $ \mathbb{Z}_p $.

I have a question about bounding incomplete sums of these characters.

Let $ T $ be a subset of $ \mathbb{Z}_p $ of size $ (p-1)/2 $. I want statistics on sums of the form: 
$$
 \sum_{t \in T} \chi_\alpha(t) 
$$

In the worst-case, we know that this sum can be as large as $ c\cdot p $ where $ c $ is some constant. (e.g. when $ \alpha  = 0 $ or $ \alpha =1 $ and $ T = \{ 1, 2, \dots, (p-1)/2 \}$ )

Can we say something stronger about the expectation? That is, for every subset $ T $, the expectation: 
$$ \mathbb{E}_{\alpha \gets \mathbb{Z}_p} \sum_{t \in T} \chi_\alpha(t)   $$

For example, is it bounded by $ p^{\frac{1}{2}} $?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trivial estimate here would be
  $$ \mathbb E\,\Bigg|\sum_{t\in T}\chi_\alpha(t)\Bigg|
        \le \Bigg( \mathbb E\,\Bigg| \sum_{t\in T} \chi_\alpha(t) \Bigg|^2 \Bigg )^{1/2} = \Bigg( \sum_{t_1,t_2\in T} \frac1p\sum_{\alpha\in\mathbb Z_p} \omega^{\alpha\cdot(t_1-t_2)} \Bigg)^{1/2} = \sqrt{|T|} \le p^{1/2}. $$
Does this answer your question?

Comment: One can see that this bound is sharp to within a constant factor, as long as $|T| \leq p/2$, by considering a random subset $T$.

Comment: Also, without the absolute values, one has ${\mathbb E} \sum_{t \in T} \chi_\alpha(t) = 1_{0 \in T}$.